# D3js d.x is undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, undefined

I'm new to d3 and have to deal with an error here.

Can someone explain to me why my code always crashes at `d.x` and says "Cannot read property x of undefined"

I tried code from examples but the error still present. Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var elementWidth = 300,
            elementHeight = 150,
            screenWidth = 1000,
            screenHeight = 800,
            svg = null;

        var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                    .origin(function (d) { return d; })
                    .on("drag", dragged);
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
                    .on("zoom", zoomed);

        var nodes = [{ id: 0, x: 10, y: 10 }, { id: 1, x: 600, y: 10 }];
        var links = [{ source : 0 , target : 1 }];

        function createView() {
            alert();
                d3.select("body")
                    .attr("width", screenWidth)
                    .attr("height", screenHeight);

                svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", screenWidth)
                .attr("height", screenHeight)
                .call(drag);
            }

            function addNewNodes() {
                //change parameters

                for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
                {
                    svg.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", nodes[i].x)
                    .attr("y", nodes[i].y)
                    .data([ {"x":nodes[i].x, "y":nodes[i].y} ])
                    .attr("width", elementWidth)
                    .attr("height", elementHeight).call(drag);
                }

                
            }

        /* DRAG & ZOOM */
        
            function zoomed()
            {
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }
            
            
            function dragged(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
            }

        /* DRAG & ZOOM END*/
            this.createView();
            this.addNewNodes();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have defined `drag` and `zoom` twice, once as a `var`, once as a `func`. That could cause problems.

Comment: @Thilo Ok i changed that but now I'm getting an error inside of the d3 library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="graph.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
var elementWidth = 300,
    elementHeight = 150,
    screenWidth = 1000,
    screenHeight = 800,
    svg = null;

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function (d) {
              return { x: d.x, y: d.y };
            })
            .on("drag", dragging);
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoom);

var nodes = [{ id: 0, x: 10, y: 10 }, { id: 1, x: 600, y: 10 }];
var links = [{ source: 0, target: 1 }];

function createView() {
  d3.select("body")
      .attr("width", screenWidth)
      .attr("height", screenHeight);

  svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", screenWidth)
  .attr("height", screenHeight);
  //.call(drag);
}

function addNewNodes() {
  //change parameters

    svg.selectAll("rect").data(nodes).enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y })
    .attr("width", elementWidth)
    .attr("height", elementHeight)
    .call(drag);
}

/* DRAG & ZOOM */

function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}


function dragging(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

/* DRAG & ZOOM END*/
this.createView();
this.addNewNodes();

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

First, you need to have a unique name for your drag handler, then you need to access the correct atributes (`x` and `y` not `cx` and `cy`)

```
function dragging(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
}
```

Then you need to connect it to the drag events...

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function (d) {
              return { x: d.x, y: d.y };
            })
            .on("drag", dragging);
```

Then you need to bind your data.  The standard d3 way to do this is...

```
    svg.selectAll("rect").data(nodes).enter().append("rect")
```

You can't put `.call(drag)` on the svg element because it has no data bound so `d` will be undefined.  So you have to remove that. (`//.call(drag)`).

Also, you don't need a loop in `addNewNodes`, d3 takes care of that.

Comment: Great that works!
But the second rect flies aways when dragged.

Comment: Ah, yes, the data binding is not quite right... have to bind to the svg then select down. Give me a minute...

Comment: Actually it was only a typo... fixed

Answer (score 0):

You will get ( d , i ) arguments only when you assign there is data bound to object on which event is happening. So if you want ( d , i ) parameters when you drag rectangle, bind data x and y while creating them.

```
          svg.append("rect")
                .attr("x", nodes[i].x)
                .attr("y", nodes[i].y)
                .data([ {"x":nodes[i].x, "y":nodes[i].y} ])
                .attr("width", elementWidth)
                .attr("height", elementHeight).call(drag);
```

Comment: Tried that but now I'm getting this error: "Unhandled exception at line 3, column 9547 in http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"

Comment: can u update ur above code snippet and so that I can Run and check